# How to upgrade from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.0 in windows 2003

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, wcf

I have to deploy my WCF service on IIS 7.0 in windows 2003. Currently windows2003 has IIS 6.0 installed already. I like to know:

1. How/Steps to upgrade from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.0?
2. Is there any installer for IIS 7.0. I am googling it but it gives the reference of setup that upgrade my internet explorer to 7.0.

Please provide me links to acheive that!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot upgrade IIS to version 7 on Server 2003 - you would have to upgrade your server OS to Windows Server 2008 in order to run IIS 7 (it is an integral part of the OS).

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, IIS7 is now supported on Server 2003 with SP1:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2299 (Click System Requirements)

Comment: FYI that's just IIS7 Manager, not the full IIS7 web server.

Comment: Thanks, @bfhd. I should have clarified.